# substitution for uncle and aunt

Tags: word-request

I know in the English the words of **aunt** and **uncle** are used to address our parent's brother and sister. But, I want to know whether there exists a specific lexical item for our (mother/father)'s brother and also for (mother/father)'s sister. For example, when one says my uncle has two sons, I promptly ask whether he is your mother's brother or father's. There is a way to distinguish between them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are many languages that differentiate relatives much more than English does. So you can have different words for aunts, uncles, grandmothers, and grandfathers on your mother's side and your father's side. I suspect your native language is one of these.

English doesn't do this. The distinction isn't important enough to require separate words for each. We usually don't bother specifying the relationship any further, and when we do we add the words "maternal" (formal) for our mothers' side and "paternal" (formal) for our fathers' side before the word for the relative. Informally, we just say "uncle/aunt on my mum's/dad's side". However, this doesn't completely define the relationship for aunts and uncles. If I say "paternal aunt" it's either my father's sister, or my father's brother's wife (my father's sister-in-law). (Note that my father's sister-in-law can also mean his wife's sister, who is not related to me if my father's wife is not my mother.)

Some languages also have terms for older brother, younger brother, older sister, younger sister, etc. Using these words shows respect by acknowledging a hierarchy within a family. Not only does English not have the equivalent words, we also have a word "sibling" which is either a brother or a sister without specifying the gender. Many languages don't have a word for "sibling", e.g. instead of asking "Do you have any siblings?" you have to ask "Do you have any brothers or sisters?"

So, in English we have different words depending on the gender of the relative, but not different words for exactly how they're related. Many of our terms are ambiguous without going into more detail. We also have non-gender-specific words for most relations: parent, child, sibling, grandparent, grandchild, cousin. We don't have non-gender-specific words for aunt, uncle, niece, or nephew.

The many comments this answer has attracted shows how the words mean just what they mean, no more, no less. An aunt can be on your mother's side or your father's side. She could be related to you by blood (one of your parents' siblings) or she could be related to you by marriage (one of your uncles' wives). English doesn't specify any further than that, and usually it's not important enough to clarify the situation.

Your language might not have words for "one parent's brother" or "one parent's sister". A native English person learning your language might find this strange but they would cope after a while. Not having more specific words than "aunt" or "uncle" might seem strange to you, but it's the norm in English to not be more specific. Our language is influenced by our culture and our culture is influenced by our language. Apparently, there is no cultural or linguistic need in English for more specific words.

Both of my parents are only children, so I have no natural aunts or uncles. Everyone I call "Aunt" or "Uncle" is actually a great-aunt or great-uncle (my grandparents' siblings), or a cousin of an appropriate age (i.e. roughly my parents' age).

Something about different languages is that although they can all express the same ideas, often there are no direct translations. This is one of those cases. The most natural way is to just say "aunt" or "uncle". Only specify it further if it's important to do so.

Comment: Though it would be rare to have "maternal" or "paternal" used in ordinary speech.  It's used only when there's some reason to make a distinction.  Likewise, there are a lot of relationship terms, like "second cousin once removed" that are mostly used by geneaology nuts, and not understood by the rest of us.  They seem to change with time, too: in Shakespeare, "cousin" seems to include what we'd call nieces and nephews.

Comment: @jamesqf You could say a nephew/niece is a zeroth cousin once removed, right?

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Lol. Technically, yes.

Comment: "(Note that my father's sister-in-law can also mean his wife's sister, who is not related to me.)" Unless your father and mother were divorced and your father had remarried, this would just be your maternal aunt, no?

Comment: @jamesqf In ordinary speech, people are more likely to say "on my mom's side" than "maternal", or "on my dad's side" than "paternal".

Comment: "(Note that my father's sister-in-law can also mean his wife's sister, who is not related to me.)"  I knew a pair of brothers who married sisters, so they had double sisters in law.

Comment: Also, your Aunt or Uncle may not be your father's or mother's sibling but a spouse of their sibling.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO Most people don't use "zeroth". Technically, your siblings are your "zeroth cousins", but no-one would ever say that (except in jest), just as aunts, uncles, nieces, and nephews are not called "zeroth cousins once removed".

Comment: There are gender-neutral English words for ‘aunt’/‘uncle’ and ‘nephew’/‘niece’: ‘auncle’ and ‘nibling’.  These are both used when needed in academic literature but not widely in colloquial English.  But then, the same was true of ‘sibling’ a century ago.

Comment: @TobyBartels I've never heard of these words before and I wouldn't tell a learner that they exist. Learners shouldn't use obscure words, they should be taught the most idiomatic forms only.

Comment: @CJDennis Sure. I was just trying to be funny and reconcile the quoted Shakespearean cousin with today's use.

Comment: How can you have cousins if you don't have any aunts or uncles?

Comment: @TonyK They're all second cousins or more, but still cousins!

Comment: @Angew is no longer proud of SO: Got me.  Some people understand, and apparently take pleasure in understanding, the minutae of relationships.  A lot of people don't.  (And as you might guess, I'm one of them :-))

Comment: @CJDennis :  I'm not saying that you should tell learners that they exist, but now that you know about them, I hope that you wouldn't tell anybody that they *don't* exist.  I won't be so presumptuous as to edit your text in this way, but if I were, then I'd change ‘We don't have non-gender-specific words for aunt, uncle, niece, or nephew.’ to ‘We don't have non-gender-specific words for aunt, uncle, niece, or nephew in common usage.’ or something along those lines.

Comment: @TobyBartels I still wouldn't tell a learner that. It's irrelevant information. By the way, only one of these neologisms seems to have gained any acceptance. Just because someone makes up a word doesn't mean it will be accepted or survive. There are many famous authors who invented lots of word, only a few of which we still use today.

Comment: @CJ Dennis:  I don't understand.  I'm not suggesting that you tell anybody anything; in my hypothetical edit, I would make you tell people *less* things, making your statement weaker so that it becomes true.  (And these words are in no danger of dying out.  They might or might not spread from the academy to common usage like ‘sibling’ did, but they're established in their current contexts.)

Comment: "We don't have non-gender-specific words for aunt, uncle, niece, or nephew **in common usage**" means that those words do exist. It's natural to then ask "What are those words?" Such trivial information can be of no practical use to a learner. In fact it's not even useful for me as a native speaker, because no other native speaker I know would understand those words.

Answer (score 9):

One more phrase you can use, "on my (mom/mother)'s side" or "on my (dad/father)'s side". This is less formal than maternal/paternal, and understood by more people.

So you can say, "Uncle John, my uncle on my mom's side, passed away over the weekend, so that side of the family is all flying in for the funeral."

Answer (score 4):

No, we don't have specific nouns for that.  You could say "maternal/paternal uncle".

Comment: And moreover, culturally we don't make a big issue of maternal or paternal.  If someone told that "my uncle has two sons" I wouldn't ask if it was a maternal or paternal uncle, that would be irrelevant to me.  Note furthermore that your aunt's husband is also an "uncle" even though not related to you by blood.

Answer (score 1):

Other posters have covered [the common, Germanic way to express this idea ("on my X's side")](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/239288/52137) and [the more formal, educated, Latinate way ("my paternal" or "material Y")](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/239260/52137). There *are* some other still rarer forms you can use. Basically, **you can use** (and people have historically used) **almost any Latin or Greek word for family members in an anglicized form**, *if* you don't mind people not understanding you and needing an explanation.

An [*agnate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agnate) or [*agnatic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/agnatic) relative is one tracable only through the male line; they're a little more specific than *paternal* since (e.g.) they wouldn't cover your father's sister's husbands. Such relationships are [*patrilineal*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/patrilineal), but you wouldn't normally use that word to describe the person himself. This mostly only shows up in old legal English.

Similarly, an [*enate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enate#English) or [*enatic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/enate#English) relative is one tracable only through the female ([*matrilineal*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/matrilineal#English)) line and wouldn't describe your mother's brother's wife. This almost never shows up at all; old legal English used [*cognate*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cognate#English) to describe any relation on one's mother's side. In present-day English, *cognate* is mostly only used to describe historically related *words*, rather than people.

You can distinguish *blood relations* from relations *by marriage*, but you don't normally call someone your *blood aunt*. Similarly, it's very uncommon to say *aunt-in-law*. You could say someone is *my aunt by blood*, but it'd be more normal to just call her *my aunt* and distinguish other women as *my aunts by marriage*. Similarly, *she's an in-law* is mostly used only for the relatives of your spouse and not other people related by marriage elsewhere in your family tree.

In other words, like @CJDennis's answer said, **there are ways to express every familial relationship in English, but we mostly don't bother to do so**. There's no important hierarchy of status like in Chinese, so there aren't dedicated words for each one. You have to just explain the relationship.

**Side point:** Many ESL speakers will explain the relationship as a chain: *He's my dad's brother's husband*. That's clear and gets your point across, but it's also a little unnatural for native speakers because it implies there's no relationship to the speaker. *She's my new mom* versus *She's my dad's new wife* imply **very** different relationships: the second implies that the speaker (at minimum) doesn't feel very close or loving towards the woman. The way to express your relationship to family members you accept as family is not to use a chain but to explain who they are from your own perspective: *he's Uncle Bob's husband* or *he's the partner of one of my uncles on my dad's side of the family*.

That's *why* we say it that way, if you were curious.